# filtrar datos en SQL con fecha pero solo tomando mes y año

Tags: sql, date, count

Tengo una tabla de reportes en la cual se registra `cliente fecha reporte`
en un `datagrid`. Tengo que mostrar cuantas veces han reportado dichos *clientes*. Esto lo hago con `count` y los filtro según el mes actual con la siguiente consulta:

```
select nombre_c, DateName(month,fecha), count(*) AS Total from reportes where month(fecha) = MONTH(GETDATE()) group by nombre_c, DateName(month,fecha)
```

Pero el detalle es, que solo me toma el mes, y quiero tambien me tome en cuenta el año ya que si tengo reportes del `11 de noviembre del 2021` y del `26 de noviembre de 1984` al momento de realizar la consulta, me muestra **cliente-noviembre-2**

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos cuál es el motor de bases de datos que usas? Y, además, nos vendría bien el esquema de la tabla para poder reproducir tu problema. PD: ¿conoces la existencia del operador lógico `AND`?

Comment: La palabra mágica es AND, y los ingredientes son conocimiento e imaginación. No obstante, puedes filtrar así: WHERE fecha LIKE '2021-11-%', al menos si estás en MySql/MariaDb y el campo es de tipo date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas es usar el operador lógico `AND` para que se cumpla la condición de año y mes:

```
SELECT
  nombre_c,
  count(*) AS Total
FROM reportes
WHERE
  MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(GETDATE())
  AND YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY nombre_c
```

Si necesitas mostrar el mes actual (como en tu SQL de ejemplo) puedes mantener:

```
SELECT
  nombre_c,
  DATENAME(month, fecha),
  count(*) AS Total
FROM reportes
WHERE
  MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(GETDATE())
  AND YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY nombre_c, DATENAME(month, fecha)
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=b919b65f3979e8df9c01abf9a4b0e239